# Cloud Data Fusion storagebucketslist permission issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdap, google-cloud-data-fusion

I just installed Cloud Data Fusion, and get this error when I try to explore the “Cloud Storage Default” bucket. How do I fix this?

`cloud-datafusion-management-sa@xxxxxxxxxxxx-tp.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project xxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/granting-service-account-permission

Answer (score 8):

Data Fusion Beta requires an additional step after creating an instance to grant its service account permissions on the project where it is created. This step is required only once per project.

To grant these permissions, follow these steps:

1. Visit the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Navigate to the instance detail page by clicking on the instance name
   [image: Cloud Data Fusion instance list]
3. Copy the service account
   [image: Cloud Data Fusion service account details]
4. Navigate to the IAM Page of your project.
5. On the IAM Permissions page, grant the service account the Cloud Data Fusion Service Agent role, by clicking the Add button.
   [image: Cloud Data Fusion IAM settings]

Once these steps are done, you can start using Cloud Data Fusion by clicking the View Instance link on the Cloud Data Fusion instances page, or the details page of an instance.

For more details, please refer to the [Cloud Data Fusion reference documentation on permissions.](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-instance#setting_up_permissions)

Comment: Is this answer still correct, now that Cloud Data Fusion is no longer in beta? This page says that the service account you mentioned is deprecated: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts